# Excessively Large Partitions

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

Receiving the follow information from the Best Practice service in OpsCenter, what's the reason?

> The following tables have excessively large partitions:
>
> fabrikam.data_example_by_minute (177 mb)
> fabrikam.data_example_by_second (637 mb)
>
> Consider remodeling your data to break up wide partitions.